# RenderBody() that fills up the full width of page

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I am using MVC 5 and I'm trying to create a `<div>` that fills up the whole width of the page which isn't part of the `Layout` or doesn't consider as the `header` or `footer`. Based on my understanding, `RenderBody()` only fills up the middle section of the page. How do I implement this? I've tried setting `width: 100%` however it just fills 100% of the `body` of the page.

```
<div class="new-container" style="width:100%">
    <h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

I've also tried changing the `padding` in the `css` file to `0 px` but it does not work since the `html` file is called using `RenderBody()` in the `Layout` page.

Comment: Aren't you missing any tags for your question?